# Access Flask session in behave steps

Tags: python, session, flask, python-behave

I'm using Flask and `behave`, following the instructions [here](https://github.com/behave/behave/pull/601).

I'm accessing pages using the Flask test client (rather than through a browser via something like Selenium).  For example, calling `get` on the test client to get a response.

I'd like to access Flask session data in my steps.  There are various techniques documented on the [Testing Flask Applications](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/testing) page about accessing context and sessions, but I can't see that any of them are quite what I need when using behave, in particular as I'll be accessing the page in one step and then wanting to retrieve session in another.

My `environment.py` looks like this:

```
from my_app import app


def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    app.testing = True
    # load the test config to ensure e.g. right database used
    app.config.from_object('parameters.test')
    context.client = app.test_client()


def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flask testing technique that came closest to what I needed was [this one](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/testing/#accessing-and-modifying-sessions):

```
with app.test_client() as c:
    rv = c.get('/')
    assert flask.session['foo'] == 42
```

The problem I had with this is that I needed to make the `get` request in one step and check the session later in another - i.e. the code was in different functions, so couldn't all be wrapped in the `with` block.

**Reading sessions**

The [with statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) is essentially syntactic sugar for a pattern similar to try/finally (see link), so I could break this down a bit, giving me the following `environment.py`:

```
from my_app import app


def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    # all the code I had before still here
    # ...
    # and this new line:
    context.client.__enter__()


def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    # the exit code doesn't actually use its parameters, so providing None is fine
    context.client.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

In my steps, I can now do `from flask import session` and access `session` as I would in my normal application.  You can access `request` in the same way.

**Writing sessions**

As the Flask testing page says, this approach "does not make it possible to also modify the session or to access the session before a request was fired."

If you need to do that, you need to extend the pattern slightly further.  First (in `before_scenario`), assign the return value from `__enter__()` to a variable you can access later:

```
context.session = context.client.__enter__()
```

then, in your steps, you can do this:

```
with context.session.session_transaction() as sess:
    sess['key here'] = some_value
```

This is the second pattern described in the section linked to at the start of my answer.  The only modification is that you need to store the return value from `__enter__()` since you're not using a `with` statement.